# Saml sp module issue in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, saml

We are getting issue with saml module when we select NAMEID format to unspecified. Its working fine if we select NAMEID format to Email.

Its give error shown below

```
a:6:{s:5:"%type";s:12:"PDOException";s:8:"!message";s:335:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table &#039;enabds.field_data_unspecified&#039; doesn&#039;t exist: SELECT nameid.entity_id AS entity_id
FROM 
{field_data_unspecified} nameid
WHERE  (unspecified_value = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array
(
    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; 
)
```

Please suggest